# Chrome Developer Tools do not show form data on Windows Server 2012

Tags: google-chrome, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm running Chrome version 61.0.3163.91 (Official Build) (64-bit) as Administrator (also tried a regular user, no difference) on a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM on AWS and I want to debug POST data being sent to my application, but the Google Chrome developer tools don't show the form data at all:

[image: simple example of a POSTed form on jsfiddle]

Comment: Workaround: just use FireFox which does show it, might be a bug in Chrome on this OS?

Comment: This is not only on Windows Server, it is also happening on Windows 10.

Comment: The issue is being tracked here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=766715#c4

Comment: @RelaXNow: Firefox gets another problem: cannot see the cookie

Comment: I guess it's not OS depending bug. On Windows 7 same problem.